# Most efficient way to recalculate enemy A* path on the fly?

Tags: ai, performance, path-finding, efficiency

I'm working on implementing a more robust pathfinding algorithm for the enemies in my top-down shooter game, and I have the A* algorithm working, but now I need to decide when to calculate the path.

There are a couple situations where the path will be calculated already:

1. The enemy sees the player.
2. The enemy hears a sound.

I figure that I'll have the enemy continually recalculate their path to make sure they're aiming at the player and not just wandering off to the last path goal even after the player has moved. I also plan to have them initially only head to the last sound they heard or the last place they sighted the player if the player is no longer visible, and only continue pathing if they sight the player again or hear a new noise.

However, while they actively have the player in their sights and are charging toward him, how should I determine when to recalculate their path? I have a couple ideas already, but I'm not sure which would be most efficient, or if there's a better way.

1. Using grid coordinates corresponding to the map tiles, if the player moves 1 or more grid squares away from his initial position, determined by calculating `(x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2`. If this way is efficient enough, should each enemy be doing this calculation in their update step? Or should there be some sort of "notify" implementation (this would be a good amount more work because I don't have any kind of signal/slot pattern set up).
2. If the sum of the X and Y offsets of the enemy's grid coordinates compared to the player's coordinates are getting bigger, recalculate.

Anyone have any ideas? A* isn't exactly a cheap operation, so I want to limit the amount of recalculating I'm doing, especially if there are a good deal of enemies in the map.

Comment: Have you looked into resumable A*? This could let you re-use substantial parts of the computation you've already done, and limit the search area to a few extra steps beyond the previous frontier in many cases.

Comment: @DMGregory No, I actually haven't heard of that. If I made that modification, do you think it would be fast enough that 50+ agents could recalculate every step? Or would I still need to optimize somewhere? Although I didn't mention it in my post, my game is written in Java.

Comment: That's something you'll need to evaluate, based on your implementation, the situation you're in, etc.

Comment: A quick optimization would probably be that if the enemy is close, then changes effects the situation more, so an agent that is close might need to reevaluate every frame. However an agent that is far away might only need to reevaluate every tenth frames. It could even be function of the distance (e.g. framesToNextEvaluation = distance / 10)